# Importation of many data (.txt and csv) together in R with lapply and list.files

Tags: r

My Greetings to you
I am importing data (.txt and csv) together. There 5 files .txt forms and 1 file csv. After importing, I receive this error message

> "Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument"

I used the following code.

```
getwd()
data<-list.files(getwd(),  
                 pattern=".txt|csv",
                 all.files = FALSE,full.names=FALSE, 
                 recursive=FALSE, ignore.case=FALSE, 
                 include.dirs=FALSE,no..=FALSE)
class(data)
data_appli<- lapply(data[1:5], read.table, 
                    header = TRUE, dec =".",
                    sep= "\t", quote="\n", skip=0)

GEU<-read.csv2(data[6], row.names=1, 
               stringsAsFactors= TRUE)
data_appli[[6]]<-GEU
```

Comment: It is always difficult to tell where things go wrong without a reproducible example. Can you verify "where" the error occurs? Run `data.appli <- ...` and then `GEU <- ...` to locate the problem.  Typically, I get this error with problems with the path. Check also , if `data[[6]]` gives you a proper vector that `read.csv2()` can work on.

Comment: I doesn't make sense to say 'after importing', because in that case the importing would have worked. Can you tell in which line the error occurs? Is it in the reading of data[1:5], or in reading data[6] or after it? It would be useful to include in the example only the minimum lines where the error really occurs in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: You suggest there's one csv, but your read.table argument uses the tab separator (`"\t"`). Are all files in `data` tab separated?